# Program crashing after trying to read a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My program:

I have view `parentView` and `childView`. `childView` has a `UITextField`. This `UITextField` is completed by the user. Then `UITextField.text` is passed as a `NSString` to `parentView` via a `NSNotificationCenter`. The `NSLog` in the Notification method shows that the value has been passes successfully to `parentView`.

Now the issue.... when I try to access `_guideDescription` (that contains the value being passed) in the `saveIntoExisting` my app crashes. I dont understand why is crashing when it was able to retrieve the value in the notification method.

There is no error just `(llbs)`.

Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(notificationSelectedDescription:)
     name:@"selectedDescription"
     object:nil];
}
- (void) notificationSelectedDescription:(NSNotification *)notification {


    _guideDescription = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"selected"];

    NSLog(@"Show me: %@",[_guideDescription description]);
}

- (IBAction)createExercise:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (![self fetch]) {
        NSLog(@"It doesnt exist already");
        [self save];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"It does exist already");
        /*
         * ADD CODE ON HOW TO ACT WHEN EXISTS
         */
        [self saveIntoExisting];
    }
}
- (void) saveIntoExisting {

    NSLog(@"saveintoExisting 1");
    NSLog(@"saveintoExisting show me: %@",[_guideDescription description]);


    NSFetchRequest *fetchExercise = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityItem = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchExercise setEntity:entityItem];


    [fetchExercise setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exerciseName == %@",_originalExerciseName]];

    [fetchExercise setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User", nil]];
    fetchExercise.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user.email LIKE %@",_appDelegate.currentUser];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray* oldExercise = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchExercise error:&error] mutableCopy];

    Exercise *newExercise = (Exercise*) oldExercise[0];
    newExercise.exerciseName = _exerciseName.text;
    newExercise.exercisePic = _selectedImage;



    if (![_guideDescription isEqualToString:@""]) {
        newExercise.exerciseDescription =_guideDescription;

    }
    if (_youTubeLink){
        newExercise.youtube =_youTubeLink;
    }
    if (![_selectRoutine.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"add to routine"]) {
        newExercise.routine = [[self getCurrentRoutine] exercise];
        [[self getCurrentUser] addRoutines:[[self getCurrentRoutine] exercise]];

    }


    [[self getCurrentUser] addExercisesObject:newExercise];

    error = nil;
    [context save:&error ];


}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is because of the NSString? Are you using ARC? Otherwise it may have been deallocated before `-saveIntoExisting`.

Comment: I dont know what ARC is. but I am building it very generically?

Comment: ARC is 'Automatic Reference Counting'. That means you don't have to (auto)release anymore. What do you mean with 'I am building it very generically'?

Comment: I am not including any release in my code and it works. so i guess i am.

Comment: for this task you should prefer using delegation over notification

Comment: How did you obtain it? It may have been autoreleased initially, and thus could have been deallocated because the autoreleasepool was drained between receiving the notification and `-saveIntoExisting`. It  wasn't released while part of the notification, because it was retained by the `userInfo` dictionary of the notification, but as soon as the notification got deallocated, it's `userInfo` dict released all it's values.

Comment: @11684 but the output is based on _guideDescription in the notification not on user info. what do you mean how do i got it?

Comment: Where did you instantiate the string/from which method did you obtain it? I'm pretty sure `selectedDescription` is not a standard iOS notification.

Comment: I didn't instantiate? I started using it in the notification method

Comment: "There is no error just (llbs)" That's just not helpful. There is an exception here. Catch it and read what it tells you.

Comment: @11684 the issue was that i needed to instantiate the _guideDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"selected"]] and now it works. post that as an answer, thank you!

Comment: Who gave me a minus and why?

Comment: @JonathanThurft The one who posted the notification instantiated the string. Did you post that notification?

Comment: @11684 the method that received the notification instantiated the string.

Comment: @JonathanThurft No, the method that received the notification only obtained a reference to the string from the dictionary. It did not instantiate it. Instantiating is something else than assigning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that that `_guideDescription` string already is deallocated when you try to access it in `-saveIntoExisted`. You are now doing

```
_guideDescription = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"selected"]];
```

and that works, but I would recommend:

```
[_guideDescription retain];
```

That makes sure the system doesn't deallocate the string.